# Convert.ToString returns string.empty instead of null

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion

I've found out a strange behaviour of Convert.ToString and I would like to understand, why it does behave like this.

Have a look at following code pieces:

```
string obj = null;
var str = Convert.ToString(obj);
Console.WriteLine(str); // CORRECT: returns null;
```

all good so far, but:

```
DBNull obj = DBNull.Value;
var str = Convert.ToString(obj);
Console.WriteLine(str); // ???: returns string.Empty ("")
```

and

```
object obj = null;
var str = Convert.ToString(obj);
Console.WriteLine(str); // ???: returns string.Empty ("")
```

It looks to me like a bug, because when i do a conversion to a string and the input is NULL the result should be default of a string, which is also NULL.

Comment: As per msdn here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx, it is returning as it is told.

Comment: i know, but i dont understand why they want to behave their method differently on same inputs.

Comment: DBNull overrides ToString and IConvertible.ToString and they both return string.Empty. Are you sure of your result there, because Convert.ToString(IConvertible) delegates to those methods. It makes sense that Convert.ToString((string)null) just returns the parameter (and the reference source supports this). The source for Convert.ToString(object) returns string.Empty if it's null

Comment: right, my fault - so it's just the string overload that behaves differently. I edited my question and checked one of the answers as solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Convert.ToString` has [a `String` overload that does nothing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns the specified string instance; no actual conversion is performed.

and [its `Object` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx) is defined thus:

> The string representation of *value*, or `String.Empty` if *value* is **null**.

It might be a bit surprising, but there’s no reason to use `Convert.ToString` on a `String` *expression* in the first place.

Comment: I was literally just looking at [the code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/convert.cs#L1808) for that and for [string input](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/convert.cs#L1959-L1967) :)

Comment: thanks guys for the docs and the code. i know now, that is coded that way. but it looks to me a bit suspicious and inconsistent.

Comment: @maerlin `DBNull.Value` also returns `String.Empty` for me, so it seems pretty consistent.

Comment: you're right - my fault then.. but still not consistent (at least on my point of view).Because they receive the same input values (string NULL and object NULL) and behave differently.

Comment: @maerlin the reference source has a comment that says "skip the null check" which makes sense. You know you have a parameter of type string, so just return it. It doesn't make sense to call Convert.ToString(string) anyways, it's essentially a no-op masked behind a method call. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,62a50ad9f30e9ac2

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I think the more interesting comment is "We were always skipping the null check here.", indicating that this has some historical reason. Now I start wondering why the string overload exists in the first place...

Comment: @Freggar that's on the contract line and I think it's in reference to the line below it. I suspect code contracts were added in much later than the original framework (though just a guess). Compare the Contract.Ensures with the other methods which do a `!=null`, whereas these do a `==value`

Comment: so the answer, why it skips the null checks (and thus you receive null instead of "" in that special case) on one overload would be: historical.

Answer (score 9):

That's documented behaviour

[`Convert.ToString Method (Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The string representation of value, or String.Empty if value is null.

---

[`Convert.ToString Method (String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2xyyx8(v=vs.110).aspx)

> value is returned unchanged.